# How to perform MySQL Left Join on 5 nested tables?

Tags: mysql, nested, left-join

I have the following database structure:

[image]

where the `prefix_dt` table connects with `prefix_ue` and `prefix_di` tables directly and the `prefix_di` table connects with `prefix_dr` and `prefix_dp` tables directly.

I am currently running the following MySQL query to obtain the data from all 5 tables:

```mysql
SELECT 
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pdt.id as id, 
  CONCAT(
    pue.first_name, ' ', pue.last_name
  ) as name, 
  pdi.download, 
  pdi.version as version, 
  pdi.release_title, 
  pdt.accepted_licence as accepted_licence, 
  pdt.download_date as download_date 
FROM 
  prefix_dt pdt 
LEFT JOIN prefix_ue pue ON pue.users_id = pdt.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    pdi.id, 
    pdi.version as version, 
    pdr.title as release_title, 
    pdp.title as download 
  FROM 
    prefix_di pdi 
    LEFT JOIN prefix_dr pdr ON pdr.id = pdi.release_id 
    LEFT JOIN prefix_dp pdp ON pdp.download_id = pdi.download_id 
  WHERE 
    pdp.language_id = 1
  ) as pdi ON pdt.download_item_id = pdi.id 
WHERE 
  1 = 1 
GROUP BY 
  pdt.id 
ORDER BY 
  id asc 
LIMIT 
  0 , 10
```

I have 3 Million records in the `prefix_dt` tables and so the query takes around 20 seconds to run. I have tried sub queries as well without any luck. I am limited to limited to utilize the same database structure. Anyone knows a better way to get the data in a single query and not have it take 20+ seconds?

Here is the DB Fiddle with sample data: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eEGX8Z2gxrEzhptZsDF9hR/1

Comment: This is a big question, and without seeing/getting familiar with your data, it might be hard to give an answer.  You should take some time and research learning how to view an execution plan in MySQL.  Your query might need to be written better, or you might to add indices, or both.

Comment: Does your data change a lot and do you use this query a lot? If the answer is NO for data change and YES for using it a lot, you can create a "Materialized view" : you create a 6th table that get all the column you want with those data and then you can make query on it. Use trigger or procedure to get data update. It's faster than using 5 table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the sample data in the DB Fiddle. What else I should provide?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Yes the data changes every day and the query is also being used 
a lot.

Comment: @MickaelLeger Thank you for your tip. I created a new table and added the triggers  as you suggested. The query now takes 1 second to load the data :)

Comment: @MurtazaMalek Nice if it works :)